# Changing appearance of web parts in SharePoint 2013 using CSS

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013

I have built a site in SharePoint and would now like to change the appearance of web parts (document libraries) using CSS.

Whenever I add the following CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-webpart-titleText.ms-webpart-titleText, .ms-webpart-titleText > a {
background-color: darkblue; 
font-size: 18px;   
font-weight: bold; 
color: white;
padding: 5px 5px;}
</style>
```

...I find that the *preview* window in my web browser shows a change has taken place.
[image]

Unfortunately, when I apply the changes and view the page again, the web part has reverted to the default appearance.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Try using SharePoint designer :)

Answer (score 0):

What is likely to be happening is that wherever you are loading that CSS, it is being overridden by the standard CSS.

You can try adding the `!important` tag to the end of the entry. You should check out the code using web developer tools in the browser to make sure that the CSS is actually being loaded and not dropped by SharePoint and find out what might be taking preference to your code. Using Firefox with the Firebug addin should assist greatly.

Let us know:

- Exactly what webpart you are trying to change
- How & where you are inserting the CSS
- What page layout and master page you are using

Answer (score 0):

Your Web Part Chrome Type might be the problem. You will be able to see changes on edit mode, but if your Chrome Type is set to Default, None, or Border Only, you will not see the title on the actual page.

On your Title on the edit mode page, go to the far right, and click on the drop down menu. Click on Edit Web Part, and go to Appearance. There you should find the Chrome Type settings. This can also be done in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I would create ".txt" file store in site assets library,  and just call out this text file in content editor.

Comment: Why would you use this approach? What benefit does it have over other methods? Currently this answer is more suited to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are trying to EMBED style code, which gets deleted when you save the page. Instead, use a CEWP with an external .txt file, or you can use the Script Editor Web Part with style code.